# Different face matching rates between Azure face verify API and Azure Demo

Tags: azure, face-detection

I am using Azure Face API to tell two different persons' faces.
It was easy to use thanks to the good documentation on the MicroSoft Azure API website.
But the different confidence rate between API call and the demo on the webstie: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/face/#demo

My code is simple.
First I get the face ids of two uploaded images using face detection API.
And I just send two face ids to face verify API. Then I get the result of confidence rate that means the similarity of two faces.
I always get less confidence rate from my API call than the demo of the Azure website. About 20% less.
ex) I get 0.65123 on API call while I get the higher number like 0.85121 on the demo.

This is the Azure face API specifications to verity two faces:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/face/face/verifyfacetoface

Since I got no clue why it happens. I don't resize or crop the images on uploading.
I use the exactly same images for this test.

Is it possible for MS Azure to manipulate the values for their own interests?

I wonder if anyone has the same issue? If yes, please share your experience with me.

Comment: Can you please add more details about the detection model used.

Answer (score 0):

Different 'detectionModel' values can be provided. To use and compare different detection models, please refer to How to [specify a detection model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/specify-detection-model).

'detection_02': Detection model released in 2019 May with improved accuracy compared to detection_01. When you use the Face - Detect API, you can assign the model version with the detectionModel parameter. The available values are:

detection_01
detection_02